# How to edit apple mail's defaults (I am implementing a plugin of apple mail)?

Tags: macos, plugins, apple-mail

I am following this [tutorial](http://eaganj.free.fr/weblog/?post/2009/07/14/Demystifying-Mail.app-Plugins-on-Leopard) to learn how to implement a plugin of apple mail,but stuck at editing mail's defaults. where can I edit the settings?

The text in the tutorial is,

> Although Mail includes support for Mail bundles out of the box, it is
> disabled by default.    To enable it, we need edit Mail's defaults:
>
> % defaults write com.apple.mail EnableBundles -bool true
>
> % defaults write com.apple.mail BundleCompatibilityVersion 3

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

[image: Console information]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type those commands in **Terminal.app** ( /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app ). Remember to ommit `%` at the begining.

Comment: `-bash: fg: %: no such job` why?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer - do not enter `%` in front of the command. only: `defaults write com.apple.mail EnableBundles -bool true`

Comment: you are right, but I wonder if '%' is not needed, why it appears?

Comment: It's part of command prompt. For example on **sh** shell You have `$` for normal user and `#` for super user as the last character. `%` sign is used in **tcsh** shell. So I suppose it's printed before those commands just to let You know to input them to Terminal :)

Comment: And now I've got a compatibility issue when I launch mail.app. Console shows `4/23/14 19:55:06.356 Mail[1404]: Plugin compatibility check failed for MyPlugin.mailbundle. The plugin's Info.plist must have a SupportedPluginCompatibilityUUIDs key whose value is an array of strings that contains the compatibility UUIDs for the supported versions of Mail. The compatibility UUID value is found in the PluginCompatibilityUUID key of Mail's Info.plist` any advice?

Comment: You need to add key to Your Info.plist inside plugin bundle. It'll look like this:
`<key>SupportedPluginCompatibilityUUIDs</key>
 <array>
  <string>225E0A48-2CDB-44A6-8D99-A9BB8AF6BA04</string>
</array>`
To get Your Mail.app UUID type this into terminal:
`cat /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Info.plist | grep -A 1 UUID`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I suppose it works. "Suppose" means I still didn't succeed to register the plugin, but console information is not about compatibility any more(I have uploaded a screenshot in my original post). I think maybe the tutorial itself is out of date(it is written in 2009). Do you have any better one?

Comment: No problem. Now it seems to be sandbox problem. I'd suggest You make  another question about that. Unfortunatelly I don't have enough knowledge to help You with this issue.